# Glue not reading lines where values have double quotes (")

Tags: csv, aws-glue

I'm creating a dynamic frame from catalog tables in order to load data to Redshift.
When the values in the CSV file has double quotes, the line is not read by Glue. Any workaround to get Glue to read the CSV properly?

For example, if the CSV looks like this:

```
"id","Name"
"1","Michael Jordan"
"2","Lebron "GOAT" James"
```

Given this CSV file, I should be getting 2 rows, but when I check the dynamic frame, it only has 1.

This is the code used to create the dynamic frame:

```
df_src_ev_catalog = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog (
        database = catalog_db,
        table_name = catalog_tbl,
        transformation_ctx ="df_src_ev_catalog",
        push_down_predicate = str_predicate
    )
```

Since the CSV file comes from an outside source, we have to find a way to handle these without making changes on how the file is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Someone may have a process for parsing this but in the general case I know of no way to "fix" this input data.  The basic problem is information loss and not following either of the file formats that go by the term "CSV".  I think you will need to push back on the supplier of the data for a fix and here's some ammo.

CSV is a defined file format with a spec and what you have shown is not valid per that spec.  If double quotes are in the data for a quoted value these double quotes need to be escaped by another double quote. See rule 7 in https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt

Alternatively there is the more ad hoc definition of Comma Separated Values which get is loosely defined like Pipe Separated Values or Tab Separated Values.  In this scheme only the separator character is "special" and only the use of this character needs to be escaped by a backslash.  This doesn't seem to fit your data either.

If no pushback is possible and you have to use the files as-is you will need to use a simple parser to just break values at commas in glue and then try to post process the data (remove the leading and trailing double quotes).  The problem will be resolving the ambiguity when various corner cases arise - comma in a data field, data field without being quoted, change of quote character, etc.  There's been information loss in the source files and you will be constantly trying to properly guess what the "right" result should be.